# Programmatically select multiple cells in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a dynamic JTable displaying SQL-results. I'm implementing a search function and select all cells containing the value searched for.
I'm using JTable.changeSelection(row,col,true,false). Within the JTable I have implemented a function that returns an ArrayList of an object containing row and col of the found elements.
This works fine as long as there are max. 5 search results, after this it selects somehow random. This is my Code:

```
private void searchTable() {
    String pattern = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(scrollpane, "Pattern", "Find Text in Table", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (pattern != null) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                busyCursor();
                ArrayList<TableFindResult> tfr = dt.search(pattern);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tableView.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                        tableView.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

                        tableView.clearSelection();
                        int a = 1;
                        Iterator iter = tfr.iterator();
                        while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            TableFindResult t = (TableFindResult) iter.next();                                
                            tableView.changeSelection(t.getRow(), t.getCol(), true, false);

                        }
                        defaultCursor();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        t.start();

    } else {
        tableView.clearSelection();
    }

}
```

This is how it goes when less than 5 results:

[image]

now my pattern is '8', there are so many appereances even without the 8
[image]

I have debugged to verify, that the searchfunction, preparing the array works correctly. I have the impression it is the JTable.changeSelection-function, that gets a mess. But I did not find a solution up to now.
I think to select heses cells is a good idea, because my JdbcTable is able to transpose selected rows so these two functions would harmonize.
Any idea out there?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTable with cellSelectionEnabled, takes the intersections of rows selected and columns selected. For example: if you select cells (r1, c1) and (r2, c2) - JTable selects (r1,c1), (r1, c2), (r2, c1) and (r2, c2).

Override `isCellSelected` in JTable to get your intended behavior.

Adding a small example below:

```
package tableselection;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TableSelection extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };
    Object[][] data = { { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", Integer.valueOf(5), Boolean.valueOf(false) },
            { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", Integer.valueOf(3), Boolean.valueOf(true) },
            { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", Integer.valueOf(2), Boolean.valueOf(false) },
            { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), Boolean.valueOf(true) },
            { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), Boolean.valueOf(false) } };

    public TableSelection() {
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            List<Point> selected = new ArrayList<Point>();
            @Override protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getID() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)
                    return;
                int row = ((JTable)e.getSource()).rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int col = ((JTable)e.getSource()).columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if(row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
                    Point p = new Point(row, col);
                    if(selected.contains(p))
                        selected.remove(p);
                    else
                        selected.add(p);
                }
                ((JTable)e.getSource()).repaint();
            }

            @Override public boolean isCellSelected(int arg0, int arg1) {
                return selected.contains(new Point(arg0, arg1));
            }
        };
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        main.add(pane);
        this.add(main);

        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new TableSelection();
    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this tip. I have tested it and there are some side effects with other functions. This is a good base for further thinking. I have learned a lot. Thank you